# The app crashes when trying to login(using parse object)

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-asynctask, parse-platform

I am creating an app having login activity and used parse.com as the network service. I used the default loginactivity.java file in android studio. Inside my class UserLoginTask, I used the parse login methods. But I am not sure what is wrong. The app takes the email id and password. The progress bar works for a flip second and then the app shuts down.Then I get and error after sometime.

This is the loginactivty.java.

```
   package com.redux.kumardivyarajat.attendance;

   import android.animation.Animator;
   import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
   import android.annotation.TargetApi;
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
   import android.content.ContentResolver;
   import android.content.CursorLoader;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.Loader;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.os.Build.VERSION;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.provider.ContactsContract;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.text.TextUtils;
   import android.view.KeyEvent;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import com.parse.LogInCallback;
   import com.parse.ParseException;
   import com.parse.ParseUser;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;


   /**
  * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
  */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

/**
 * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
 * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
 */




/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);

    Button mSignUpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SignUpButtonInsideLogin);
    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
    //mSignUpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SignupText);

}

private void populateAutoComplete() {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        // Use ContactsContract.Profile (API 14+)
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    } else if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        // Use AccountManager (API 8+)
        new SetupEmailAutoCompleteTask().execute(null, null);
    }
}


/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    email = email.trim();
    password = password.trim();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;


    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute();

    }
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return email.contains("@");
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return password.length() > 4;
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            // Select only email addresses.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                    " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
            .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

            // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
            // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

}

private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
    };

    int ADDRESS = 0;
    int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
}

/**
 * Use an AsyncTask to fetch the user's email addresses on a background thread, and update
 * the email text field with results on the main UI thread.
 */
class SetupEmailAutoCompleteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ArrayList<String> emailAddressCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Get all emails from the user's contacts and copy them to a list.
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
            String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract
                    .CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            emailAddressCollection.add(email);
        }
        emailCur.close();

        return emailAddressCollection;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emailAddressCollection);
    }
}

private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
    //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

    mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        /*try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;*/
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(mEmail,mPassword, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);

                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.loginup_error_title);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the error I get after a while. I think this error is because of the fact that the app closes down but the background task of fetching data from parse is still in progress. I am not sure.

```
    com.redux.kumardivyarajat.attendance E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.redux.kumardivyarajat.attendance, PID: 22430
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@43010550 is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:559)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
        at com.redux.kumardivyarajat.attendance.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask$1.done(LoginActivity.java:362)
        at com.redux.kumardivyarajat.attendance.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask$1.done(LoginActivity.java:345)
        at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:945)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please suggest what chages should I make in the UserLoginTask(asynctask) to make it work.

Edit: Adding the mainactivity.java and the activity_login2.xml.

activity_login2.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.redux.kumardivyarajat.attendance.LoginActivity"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/activity_login2">

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_weight="10.63">
            <requestFocus/>
        </AutoCompleteTextView>


        <EditText android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id ="@+id/SignupText"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_from_login"
            android:textColor="#ffff0500"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.18" />

        <Button
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/SignUpButtonInsideLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the on create method of  mainactivity.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser == null) {
        navigateToLogin();

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG,currentUser.getUsername());
    }



}

private void navigateToLogin() {
    Intent intent =  new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your scenario, BadToken error may occurs when you try to show the particular view or a dialog once you finish the current activity. Whatever happens, your doinBackground return true, but when it get execute, you may have finish the activity. So i suggest you to proceed within the onpostExecute.

Try this,

Update your Async task as follows and return the status values from doInBackground. Then perform whatever the task based on return value with on onPostExecute.

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

private final String mEmail;
private final String mPassword;
private boolean status = false;

UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
    mEmail = email;
    mPassword = password;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

    ParseUser.logInInBackground(mEmail,mPassword, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null)
            {
                status = true;
            } else {
                status = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return status;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

    if (success) {
        // success code
    } else {
        // failure code
    }
}
```